# Parse a google like unit conversion input in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Google has a unit conversion feature that takes a human readable string such as:

```
1m to feet
```

and uses this as an unit conversion / calculator instruction. it also supports calculations on left side of the 'to keyword'.

```
1 * (2 * 10) / 2m to cm
```

How would one go about implimenting a simular string interpretation in javascript?

EDIT added some sample code:

```
function UnitQuery(str) {
    var arr = str.toLowerCase().split(' '),
        len = arr.length,
        afterToKeyword = false,
        queryObj = {
            left : [],
            right : []
        },
        current = queryObj.left;

    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {       
        if (!afterToKeyword && arr[i].search('to') >= 0){
            afterToKeyword = true;
            current = queryObj.right;
        }
        current.push( arr[i] );
    }
    return queryObj;
}

console.info( UnitQuery("1 m to feet") );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by tokenizing the input .split() then taking action on the values.

Comment: if you have the string "1m to feet" in a variable like "mathquery" will split the variable mathquery.split(" ") and then use that array to take action.  Try writing some code and I'm sure we can all help you along.